# How to display all validation errors according to field required in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have one form. I have to display validation error if multiple validation errors occur then display all error or display according to the field require.

For example- I have three fields `Name, Email` and `Mobile`. If all information is incorrect then display all validation errors one by one or any one field is incorrect then display one validation error.
I can display error with the help of jQuery validation that i don't want.

```js
/*alert notification for script*/
$(".notification_reminder").fadeIn()
.css({top:-100,position:'absolute'})
.animate({top:20}, 800, function() {
    //callback
});
```

```css
.form-section
  {
padding: 30px;}

.form-section input
{
margin: 10px;
}
  
.notification_section
{
position: relative;
z-index: 8;
}
.notification_reminder
{
font-size:15px;
width:350px;
padding: 15px;
background-color:#1D9365;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.notification_reminder p
{
color:#FF0;
padding:3px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?php if(!empty($_GET['chk_name'])):
   echo"
  <div class='notification_section'>
  <div class='notification_reminder'>
  <p> Name required Min 3 and Max 20</p>
  </div>
  </div>";
endif;?>

<?php if(!empty($_GET['chk_email'])):
  echo"
  <div class='notification_section'>
  <div class='notification_reminder'>
  <p> Enter valid Email address</p>
  <div class='cross_sign'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
  </div>
  </div>";
endif;?>


<?php if(!empty($_GET['chk_mobile'])):
  echo"
  <div class='notification_section'>
  <div class='notification_reminder'>
  <p> 10 numbers only</p>
  <div class='cross_sign'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
  </div>
  </div>";
endif;?>

<div class="form-section">
<form action="process.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br />
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br />
 <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile"><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>

</div>
```

**Process.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

if ($name <3 || $name >20) {
header('Location: test2.php?chk_name=1');
}

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header('Location: test2.php?chk_email=1');
}

if(strlen($mobile)!=10 || !is_numeric($mobile)) {
    header('Location: test2.php?chk_mobile=1');
}
```

In process.php I used `header` this is the reason calling the single validation error. Is there any other way? Would you help me out in this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To do something like you're searching to do, I can propose you an implementation not so difficult to do. But you'll need to do the display of the form and the treatment in the same page.

To explain you the concept :
 1. We create an empty tab, which will contain all the errors found.
 2. We look if the tab has errors, if no, so you can do your treatment (Database request or others ...)
 3. If you had errors, so we'll display it.

Let's Do It :)

```php
<?php

//We take the post's content or put a default value (php 7 way)
$name = $_POST['name']??'';
$email = $_POST['email']??'';
$mobile = $_POST['mobile']??'';

//We create a empty errors tab
$errors = [];

//We will treat error only if the form was post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors['name'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        if (strlen($name) < 2) {
            $errors['name'][] = 'Your name must to contain minimum 2 caracteres.';
        }
        if (strlen($name) > 255) {
            $errors['name'][] = 'Your name must to contain maximum 255 caracteres.';
        }
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors['email'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['email'][] = 'Your email must to be a valid one.';
        }
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    if (empty($mobile)) {
        $errors['mobile'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    // Now we'll can do what we need to do, if the form is valid
    if (empty($errors)) {
        //All your treatments.

        //We can redirect to the next page, if you need to send some message to it, you can save on $_SESSION (for exemple a success message)
        header('LOCATION: nextpage.php');
    }
}


//It's better you put what's next in a new file for be clear (look into MVC Design Pattern)
?>

<div class="form-section">
    <form method="post"> <!-- No action for redirect to the same page -->

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <?php //This can be put in a function like : displayErrors('field')
        if (!empty($errors['name'])) {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($errors['name'] as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <li><?= $error ?></li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>
        <?php //This can be put in a function like : displayErrors('field')
        if (!empty($errors['email'])) {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($errors['email'] as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <li><?= $error ?></li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile"><br/>
        <?php //This can be put in a function like : displayErrors('field')
        if (!empty($errors['mobile'])) {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($errors['mobile'] as $error) {
                    ?>
                    <li><?= $error ?></li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

If you need more explanation, don't hesitate to let me know.

Have a nice day.

Edit For display on the top :

```php
<?php

//We take the post's content or put a default value (php 7 way)
$name = $_POST['name']??'';
$email = $_POST['email']??'';
$mobile = $_POST['mobile']??'';

//We create a empty errors tab
$errors = [];

//We will treat error only if the form was post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors['name'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        if (strlen($name) < 2) {
            $errors['name'][] = 'Your name must to contain minimum 2 caracteres.';
        }
        if (strlen($name) > 255) {
            $errors['name'][] = 'Your name must to contain maximum 255 caracteres.';
        }
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors['email'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['email'][] = 'Your email must to be a valid one.';
        }
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    if (empty($mobile)) {
        $errors['mobile'][] = 'Please fill name input.';
    } else {
        //If you need more treatments you can :)
    }

    // Now we'll can do what we need to do, if the form is valid
    if (empty($errors)) {
        //All your treatments.

        //We can redirect to the next page, if you need to send some message to it, you can save on $_SESSION (for exemple a success message)
        header('LOCATION: nextpage.php');
    }
}


//It's better you put what's next in a new file for be clear (look into MVC Design Pattern)

if (!empty($errors)) {
    ?>
    <div class='notification_section'>
        <?php
        foreach ($errors as $errorsType) { // Loop on differents inputs errors
            foreach ($errorsType as $error) { // Loop on the errors
                ?>
                <div class='notification_reminder'><?= $error ?></div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>

<div class="form-section">
    <form method="post"> <!-- No action for redirect to the same page -->

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile"><br/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Sebastien, Errors are displaying proper but can we animate it from top. I don't want to display below of text field. I have to display like alert. You can check my snippet. Errors will display from top.

Comment: If you want to display every errors on the same place (in the top in your case). You can loop on every errors, I'll edit my code for show you.